# Why is this correlation near-zero?

Tags: statistics

I have data pertaining to someone's willingness to buy a certain product (via survey) and whether or not they actually make the purchase.

Based on the data, among the people who say they are very likely to buy the product, almost all of them actually do.

However, the correlation seems to be near $0$?! Shouldn't it be nearly $100$%? Why is this the case? Am I doing something wrong?

Snippet:

```
9   1
9   1
9   0
9   1
9   1
9   1
9   1
9   1
9   1
9   1
10  1
10  1
10  1
10  1
10  1
10  1
10  1
10  1
```

Left column is rating (willingness to buy), right column is 0 if they don't buy, 1 if they do.

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of the actual data?  That might help.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Added a snippet at the border between 9 and 10. (I get 21.6% correlation for this particular snippet)

Comment: So willingness is measured on a scale from 1 to 10?

Comment: 21.6% correlation is actually not that low.  If you take 1000 random numbers and then take the same 1000 but change just one of them to be much different, that can bring the correlation from 100% down to 20%, just changing one value.  In other words correlation is very sensitive.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes, 1 to 10, but I segment by data by clusters (e.g. 1-4, 5-8, 9-10) and do correlations in each general response category. I just found it off that among 9/10's, the correlation was nearly 0 even though nearly eveyrone made a purchase. Does this make sense?

Comment: Well think of it this way, all but one of them made the purchase.  If *all* of them had made the purchase then the correlation would be zero.  That's because correlation is a normalized version of co-variance, and if one of the things doesn't vary at all then it won't have co-variance either.

Comment: So what is correlation actually measuring? I always thought it was like "if you have x, can you predict what y will be?" In this case we know overwhelmingly the result will be 1 on average.

Comment: Correlation is actually a very overused measure that is so hard to interpret in practice that most people using it mis-interpret what it means.  In fact the vectors $(1,1,1,1)$ and $(2,2,2,2)$ have correlation zero.  It measures how much the two things go up and down together, if one doesn't go up or down at all then there's nothing to measure.

Comment: So it's measuring the delta of one thing to the delta of the other? So if one thing had no delta then we don't say that one is necessarily "varying" with the other?

Comment: Yes, at the intuitive level that sounds right

Answer (score 0):

If this were all your data, then it is saying that 9/10 people who responded 9 would buy the product, and 8/8 people who responded 10 would buy the product. Thus the people who responded 10 are 10% more likely to buy the product. There are too few people who do not buy the product (in the data you have shown) to establish a strong correlation.

You need to give more data to solve this problem. A better way to display the data would be:

Rating (1 to 10)/number of people who responded with this number(x)/number of purchasers (0 to x)